# VBA - error recurrence

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make a code that when the error occur more than 3 times. The module will pause.

However, the below code keep running the error handler forever. Is there anyway to fix it?

```
Sub errorTestButton()

Dim i As Long    

On Error GoTo errorhandler
With Sheets("abc") 'there is no sheets abc, i made an error intentionally.
End With
MsgBox "no error"
Exit Sub

errorhandler:
i = 0
If i < 3 Then
    i = i + 1
    MsgBox "error"
    Call errorTestButton
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Code becomes a lot clearer when you indent it.

Comment: @pexpex223  have you tired any of the answers below ? any feedback ?

Comment: @Shai Rado Yes, the below code solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i` is being reset to `0` every time you get to `errorhandler:`, so you are stuck between 0 and 1 and never reach 3.

Also, because your `i` is local, and you are re-running your `Sub` it will reset, if you define `i` outside the `Sub` (like in the code below) it will work for you.

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Long '<--- define it outside your sub, in the Mofule level

Sub errorTestButton()

On Error GoTo errorhandler
With Sheets("abc") 'there is no sheets abc, i made an error intentionally.
End With
MsgBox "no error"
Exit Sub

errorhandler:
'i = 0 '<-- this is where you are reseting it
If i < 3 Then
    i = i + 1
    MsgBox "error"
    errorTestButton
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

---

In your specific case, you can "trap" this error in a "cleaner" approach, see code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub errorTestSheetButton()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Start_Err_Loop:
On Error Resume Next
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("abc")   'there is no sheets abc, i made an error intentionally.
If Sht Is Nothing Then
    i = i + 1
    If i > 3 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Error!"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo Start_Err_Loop
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As you reset `i` to zero right before the `i < 3` test, that test will always be true. So remove that `i = 0`.

If you want to reset the error counter for each call to `errorTestButton` then that will be enough as change. It means that if you would call `errorTestButton` multiple times, each call can generate 3 error messages.

However, if you want that counter to be global, so that you will never get more than 3 error messages in total, even if you call `errorTestButton` again, then you should declare `i` as a global variable. It would also be good if you would use a more descriptive name for that variable.